# Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID

Tags: c#, iis, com

I have written a console application that connects remotely to 8 servers, gets all IIS application pool names and status, and writes them to a SQL database.  7 of the servers work without an issue.  However, I have one server that I am getting an error on.  Below are the details:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344}
 from machine failed due to the following error: 80070005
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor,  Boolean&bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateAdminManager[TClass,TInterface](WebConfigurationMap webConfigMap, Boolean isAdminConfig)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateConfiguration(WebConfigurationMap configMap, String configPathToEdit, Boolean isAdminConfig)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration(StringrawConfigurationPath, String cacheKey, Boolean isAdminConfig)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_ApplicationPoolsSection()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_ApplicationPools()
   at II7AppPools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I have seen several forums that say to recompile as x86 instead of AnyCPU.  I have done this and yet I am still getting this error.  Has anyone received this error for anything other than the AnyCPU issue?  Could it be a permission issue and, if so, permission to what?  The user running the script is an admin on all 8 servers.

Comment: 0x80070005 is Access Denied.  Your COM object needs to be listed in the DCOM Config section under Component Services on the remote server, and the account connecting to the server needs to have "Launch and Activation" (Remote Launch and Remote Activation) as well as Access (Remote Access) against the object.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I forgot to mention that the server I am running the app from is the server that I cam getting this error. All remote servers work fine.

Comment: Then make sure all of the above exist for "Local". "Local Launch", "Local Activation", "Local Access".